# Spring DAO rewritebatchedstatements not working on SaveAll() on entities with embeddedId

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We need to insert 5 million records fast on **mysql** (no control on this instance).

Tried all below and nothing works:

1. set `rewritebatchedstatements=true` (both through url and props)
2. tried `useServerPrepStmts=true` and `useServerPrepStmts=true`
3. tried other hibernate props as below
4. `Story` has `GenerationType.Auto` so its ok, but `Task` is `EmbeddedId` so batch should work? (because no generation specified)
5. Tried `MySql5InnoDBDialect` and `MySql5DBDialect`

Batching is working (based on statistics) but `rewritebatchedstatements` is not working.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.order_inserts=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.order_updates=500

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
#spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=false
```

Sample Entities:

```
class SprintService {

   @Transactional
    public void startSprint(Epic epic, List<Stories> stories) {
        epic.save()
        .....
        stories.saveAll() // few hundreds of records
        Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>;
        for(Story story: stories)
        {
            tasks.addAll(story.getTasks());
            tasks.addAll(story.getTasks());
            tasks.addAll(story.getTasks());
            //do something
        }
        tasks.saveAll() // few million records
    }
}

@Table(name = "STORY")
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Story {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(stratergy=GenerationType.Auto)
   @Column(name="STORY_ID")
   Long id;

   @Column(name="STORY_NAME")
   String name;

   @OneToMany(cascade=MERGE, mappedBy="story", fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
   Set<Task> task;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK_XREF")
class Task {
    @EmbeddedId
    TaskPKId taskPKId;

    @Column(name = "TASK_NAME")
    String name;
    @MapsId("storyId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STORY_ID")
    Story story;

    //getters, setters

}
```

And here is the TaskPKID class:

```
@Embeddable
class TaskPKId  implements Serializable {
        long taskId;
        long taskTypeId;
        @Column(name="STORY_ID")
        long storyId;

    public long getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(long taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskTypeId(long taskTypeId) {
        this.taskTypeId = taskTypeId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The values should be boolean.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.order_updates=true
```